# Create custom function to run on function full multiple chosen dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before proceeding, let me give you a jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/310/

I have two dropdowns

```
<select id="campaign_list">
    <option value="01 - AU -Bingo Campaign1">01 - AU -Bingo Campaign1</option>
    <option value="02 - BR-Bingo  Campaign2">02 - BR-Bingo  Campaign2</option>
    <option value="03 - CA-Bingo  Campaign3">03 - CA- Bingo Campaign3</option>
    <option value="04- US - Bingo  Campaign4">04- US - Bingo  Campaign4</option>
</select>



<select id="camp_list">
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="Contra 2">Contra 2</option>
    <option value="Naturom Demonto">Naturom Demonto</option>
    <option value="Necronomicon es Mortes">Necronomicon es Mortes</option>
</select>
```

I have implied chosen library for them...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#campaign_list').chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});
  $('#campaign_list').css({'width':'100%',
                           'height':'30px',
                           'border-radius':'2px'});

  $('#campaign_list_chosen').css({'width':'100%',
                                  'height':'30px',
                                  'border-radius':'2px'});


  $('#camp_list').chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});

  $('#camp_list').css({'width':'100%',
                       'height':'30px',
                       'border-radius':'2px'});

  $('#camp_list_chosen').css({'width':'100%',
                              'height':'30px',
                              'border-radius':'2px'});    


  $("#campaign_list_chosen").find("input").on('keyup',
        function()
        {
          var final_list = '';
          var srch_array = new Array();
          var srch_option = new Array();
          var list_option = new Array();
          var str_srch = $(this).val();
          var final_list_option = new Array();    
          srch_array = str_srch.split("");
          var srch_array_lengh = srch_array.length;    
          $("#campaign_list option").each(function()
          {
               list_option.push($(this).val());
          });
          for(var lo = 0; lo < list_option.length; lo++)
          {
            var count_match = 0;
            for(var sa = 0; sa <srch_array_lengh; sa++)
            {
               if (list_option[lo].toLowerCase().indexOf(srch_array[sa]) >= 0)
               {
                 count_match++;
               }
            }
            if(count_match == srch_array_lengh)
            {
                 final_list_option.push(list_option[lo]);
            }
         }
         $("#campaign_list_chosen").find("ul").html('');
         for(var fo = 0; fo < final_list_option.length; fo++)
         {
           final_list = final_list + '<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">'+final_list_option[fo]+'</li>';
         }
         $(".chosen-results").html(final_list);
       });
});
```

As you can see, i have a code which is

```
$("#campaign_list_chosen").find("input").on('keyup',
            function()
            {
              var final_list = '';
              var srch_array = new Array();
              var srch_option = new Array();
              var list_option = new Array();
              var str_srch = $(this).val();
              var final_list_option = new Array();    
              srch_array = str_srch.split("");
              var srch_array_lengh = srch_array.length;    
              $("#campaign_list option").each(function()
              {
                   list_option.push($(this).val());
              });
              for(var lo = 0; lo < list_option.length; lo++)
              {
                var count_match = 0;
                for(var sa = 0; sa <srch_array_lengh; sa++)
                {
                   if (list_option[lo].toLowerCase().indexOf(srch_array[sa]) >= 0)
                   {
                     count_match++;
                   }
                }
                if(count_match == srch_array_lengh)
                {
                     final_list_option.push(list_option[lo]);
                }
             }
             $("#campaign_list_chosen").find("ul").html('');
             for(var fo = 0; fo < final_list_option.length; fo++)
             {
               final_list = final_list + '<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">'+final_list_option[fo]+'</li>';
             }
             $(".chosen-results").html(final_list);
           });
```

Now, if I have two make this thing work for both dropdowns, then I need to write this code twice using different id.

All I want to do is that make a function where I can pass the id of the dropdown, so that that function will using this code snippet to run it on the basis of id passed as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the common function named **commonFunctionToUpdateDD**   that you can use for both Dropdowns. It needs two parameters.
First is Select element ID and second is the jQuery object of Search box of dropdown.

```
 $("#campaign_list_chosen").find("input").on('keyup',function(){
commonFunctionToUpdateDD('campaign_list',$(this));
});

    $("#camp_list_chosen").find("input").on('keyup',function(){
commonFunctionToUpdateDD('camp_list',$(this));
});

    function commonFunctionToUpdateDD(ddId,txtSearch)
    {

            var final_list = '';
var srch_array = new Array();
var srch_option = new Array();
var list_option = new Array();
var str_srch = txtSearch.val();
var final_list_option = new Array();    
srch_array = str_srch.split("");
var srch_array_lengh = srch_array.length;    
$("#"+ddId+" option").each(function()
{
    list_option.push(txtSearch.val());
});
for(var lo = 0; lo < list_option.length; lo++)
{
  var count_match = 0;
  for(var sa = 0; sa <srch_array_lengh; sa++)
  {
   if (list_option[lo].toLowerCase().indexOf(srch_array[sa]) >= 0)
   {
       count_match++;
   }
  }
  if(count_match == srch_array_lengh)
   {
       final_list_option.push(list_option[lo]);
   }
}
$("#"+ddId+"_chosen").find("ul").html('');
for(var fo = 0; fo < final_list_option.length; fo++)
{
  final_list = final_list + '<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">'+final_list_option[fo]+'</li>';
}
$(".chosen-results").html(final_list);

    }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to pass anything to `commonFunctionToUpdateDD` explicitly. If the handler is attached with `....on('keyup', commonFunctionToUpdateDD)`, and the handler is written `function commonFunctionToUpdateDD(e) {...}`, then the two would-be parameters can both be derived from `e`.